# std::make_unique<std::thread> with lambda

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr, lambda

I'm trying to compile the following code on Visual Studio 2013:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> threadPtr;
threadPtr.reset(std::make_unique<std::thread>([&]
{
  //...

}));
```

which fails with the error:

```
error C2664: 'void std::unique_ptr<std::thread,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::
    reset(std::thread *) throw()' : cannot convert argument 1 from 
    'std::unique_ptr<std::thread,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'std::thread *'
```

This seems strange as I use `std::make_unique` in other places without problems. However, when I don't use `std::make_unique` but use `new` instead, it works:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> threadPtr;
threadPtr.reset(new std::thread([&]
{
  //...

}));
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a compiler problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::make_unique` returns a `std::unique_ptr`. But `std::unique_ptr::reset` expects a pointer. So what you're looking for is either:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> threadPtr(std::make_unique<std::thread>([&]
{
  //...

}));
```

or:

```
threadPtr.reset(std::make_unique<std::thread>([&]
{
  //...

}).release());
```

Comment: Good call. Could you also just use `threadPtr = std::make_unique...` then?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus With auto, yeah.